# Java, set date to 0/0/0

Tags: java, date

I have an object with some dates and I'd like to return them in the getter. The problem is that i need to do `Date.toString();` because I have to print them, and when the date is null I get a `NullPointerException`.

I was thinking about returning the date 0/0/0 when the date is null, but I don't know how to set this value. Is there any way? Just like `new Date(0)` returns the **1970-01-01-00:00:00**, is there anything similar to this but to return 0/0/0?

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to test if the date is null before calling `toString()`. If it is null, you can print `0/0/0`, `null date`, or whatever you like.

Comment: better approach  would be to check whether date is null or not before using it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no Date 0/0/0, by definition, as there is no Day 0 and no Month 0. A day is a member of the set {1,..,28 or 30 or 31} and month is a member of the set {1,...12}. Hence, it is impossible - and it is good that it is impossible - to express 0/0/0 as Date Object.

Answer (score 4):

The terrible `Date` and `Calendar` classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Zero-date senseless

> is there anything similar to this but to return 0/0/0?

No.

Trying to represent a `null` with a date of all zeros is the wrong way to go. There is no such thing as a date of all zeros (year, month, and day all being zero).

Instead, pick an arbitrary date to use as a special value. Document thoroughly your choice and its meaning.

Do not choose a date too distant in time. Many libraries and databases are limited in their range of values. You do not want your data to break there.

Generally I would suggest using the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, the first moment of 1970 in UTC (the `Z` means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”). This moment is used as the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) for [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the legacy date-time classes bundled with Java, and the modern date-time classes built into Java 8 and later. So many programmers and sysadmins will recognize this moment as special. The *java.time* classes include a constant for your convenience: [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

Obviously my suggestion applies to common business-oriented apps interested in forward-looking near dates, with past history not reaching back to 1970. If that does not meet your needs, pick another arbitrary value, such as 1900-01-01.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the Gregorian Calendar which has no 0 year. Also, you have to keep in mind that there is now zero month either. Setting a month to '0' would result in getting January, as the months are based on 0-index. Zero day does not exist either.
Assuming that you are getting and returning "modern" dates (AD), you could set your "lower bound" date in BC era. So, when you get a *null* date you could return a BC date to differentiate it from your actual ones. Here's the code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
cal.set(Calendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.BC); //Set the BC era
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1); //Set the year to 1 BC
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); //Set the month to January
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //Set the day to 1st
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM d G"); //Format the date
String returnedDate = df.format(cal.getTime()); //Generate a String of it for other use
```

You could customize the code to your needs if you are also getting dates from BC era (maybe by setting an even older date).

*EDIT:* Of course you could use what the others have suggested, namely checking for null and returning a `"0/0/0"` String but this may cause further problems later on, when you will try to parse the aforementioned String. Also, due to the fact that by definition 0/0/0 is not a valid date in the Gregorian Calendar (see clarification), you should avoid using this "wildcard" String and set an actual date, as I detailed above.

*CLARIFICATION:* The Gregorian Calendar does not contain neither a 0 year nor a 0 month or 0 day **by definition** and not by implementation in Java (meaning it's not an intentional limitation, it's part of its concept).

Comment: @user2642282 Yup, I saw it and I acknowledge it. I'm saying the exact same thing. But besides my clarification about the limitations of the Gregorian Calendar (which you also noted), I am supplying a solution for deusex12.

Comment: it is NOT a limitation, that there is no year 0 in the Gregorian Calendar. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)

Comment: OK, bad use of word "limitation", it's part if its concept to not contain a zero year. Can we get back to offer a viable solution to his problem and not try to play on my words? Because as I can see, you only published the definition of the Gregorian Calendar so far.

Answer (score 0):

- Class: [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html)
- Package: [Threetenabp](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

My solution was to create LocalDate constants using the EPOCH date as basis with `LocalDate.ofEpochDay()`. And instead of returning a null date ([that does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767971/5279996)) I return a LocalDate object according to the case evaluated. Then depending on what I get back the getBirthdate method in my domain I do something.

### Definition of constants

```
public class LocalDateUtils {

    public static final LocalDate EMPTY_FIELDS = createLocalDate(0);
    public static final LocalDate EMPTY_FIELD_DAY_OF_MONTH = createLocalDate(1);
    public static final LocalDate EMPTY_FIELD_MONTH = createLocalDate(2);
    public static final LocalDate EMPTY_FIELD_YEAR = createLocalDate(3);

    /**
     * Purpose: Create a date with @param epochDay days added
     * Observation: EPOCH (1970-01-01)
     */
    private static LocalDate createLocalDate(long epochDay) {
        return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(epochDay);
    }
}
```

### Implementation

```
/**
 * Purpose: Describe a birthday or a constant indicating empty field (s).
 * Observation: According to if the parameters are zeros.
 */
LocalDate getBirthdate(int year,
                       int month,
                       int dayOfMonth) {
    if (dayOfMonth == 0 && month == 0 && year == 0)
        return LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELDS;
    if (dayOfMonth == 0)
        return LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELD_DAY_OF_MONTH;
    if (month == 0)
        return LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELD_MONTH;
    if (year == 0)
        return LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELD_YEAR;
    return LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
}
```

### Usage

```
    if (getBirthdate() == LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELDS) {
    }

    if (getBirthdate() == LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELD_DAY_OF_MONTH) {
    }

    if (getBirthdate() == LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELD_MONTH) {
    }

    if (getBirthdate() == LocalDateUtils.EMPTY_FIELD_YEAR) {
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800223/5279996)

GL

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque The issue is that to use LocalDate on Android you need a minimum API level of 26. And if you have a lower level than required, you would have to use Calendar and LocalDate

Comment: Nope. For **Android <26**, see [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), and [*ThreeTenABP - How to use*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706). Explained in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800223/642706). No need to ever touch `Calendar` or `Date` again (good riddance).

Comment: @BasilBourque Great, this works; I already edited my answer :)

Answer (score -2):

This simple approach can get you what you need, as already mentioned in the comments to your question:

```
public String dateString(Date date) {   
    if (date != null)
        return date.toString();
    else
        return "0/0/0";
}
```

or

```
String dateString;
try {
    dateString = date.toString();
}
catch(NullPointerException e) {
    dateString = "0/0/0";
}
```

**Update**: the second alternative is discouraged as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Please don't use the second alternative.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula could you explain why? i'm curious, and if it is a bad practice i wasn't aware of, i'd like to improve.

Comment: @saljuama It's a bad practice to intentionally cause an exception, as exceptions should not be thrown, they should be avoided. Their main use if for debugging your code only, not for release builds.

Comment: @saljuama Sure. The main reason is just that the code is definitely easier to read using an if. It's normally not a good idea to use exceptions to control the flow of your program. You can read more about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control